# send an Image file in the body of a http post request in Angular 8

Tags: angular, file, post, file-upload, image-upload

This is the object I try to add in the body

firebaseId: "gSECLs1cH9epvlIXX85yx820Tvt2"
Instructions: undefined
category: "votes"
Imageone: File {name: "21.jpg", lastModified: 1524755773798, lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 26 2018 20:46:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 171456, …}
TaskMadeDate: Mon Feb 03 2020 11:10:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
Approved: false

This is the object that goes with post request

firebaseId: "gSECLs1cH9epvlIXX85yx820Tvt2"
category: "votes"
Imageone: {}
TaskMadeDate: "2020-02-03T05:40:29.943Z"
Approved: false

**Imageone becomes empty.**

This is my post method

return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + url, data)
  .pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log(`added = ${res}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('post'))
  );

Comment: What you are sending in Imageone and how?

Comment: I try to send an Image file in Imageone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending file in regular request instead of that use form data to pass file like this :

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('firebaseId',this.firebaseId);
formData.append('imageone',this.imageone);
```

add all your data like this and if you still not getting file in your backend then add this in your request headers.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```